# To make some div display for a longer time

Tags: functions

I have this code to display some of my div for 1 day then disappear.

This code to be placed in `functions.php`

```
function post_from_today_class($class) {
//add .new-post-today to post_class() if newer than 24hrs
    global $post;
    if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) $class[] = 'new-post-today';
    return $class;
}
```

This code to be placed on page.

```
<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>
```

With this code, my div will be displayed for a day or 2. But, I would like to ask, how to make it display for a longer time, how to make it appear for 1 or 2 months?

Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress 3.5, there are [build in time constants](https://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants) to make thing easier for you. They are

- `MINUTE_IN_SECONDS`
- `HOUR_IN_SECONDS`
- `DAY_IN_SECONDS`
- `WEEK_IN_SECONDS`
- `YEAR_IN_SECONDS`

You can probably do `30 DAY_IN_SECONDS` for a 30 day period or `4 WEEK_IN_SECONDS` for a 4 week period. Obviously, for a 2 month period you will do `60 DAY_IN_SECONDS`